# Formerly saving issue

Tags: form, plugins-formerly

We've got a large formerly custom form which we're having problem saving.
Saves fine with eleven fields but any more than that and it is not saving, returning the error message: `Couldn't save form`

Any idea why this might be a problem?

Comment: Did you check the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for related errors?  Or your web server's error logs?

Comment: Just noted there is a Formerly 1.5.0 update for 2.5 - you’ve probably spotted that?